# Angular resource middleware to catch response

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular service that looks like:

```
service('PortfolioService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/', {}, {
        stock_positions: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/stock_positions',
            isArray: false
        }
    });
}]).
```

And in a controller:

```
PortfolioService.stock_positions(function someCB(result){       
   //do something with the result
});
```

If you aren't logged in the api returns an object that looks like:

```
{
  error: "Login required",
  redirect: "/login"
}
```

I would like to have something that would catch this in the resource, handle it (redirecting to /login), and not pass on to someCB in the controller.

Is there a way to do this with $resource?

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be achieved by angular interceptor.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$location', function($location) {
      return {
       'response': function(response) {
          if(response.redirect.indexOf('/login'){
          // redirect to login
          }
          return response;
        }
      };
    }]);
```

Comment: That put me on the right track, but I still wanted to stick with $resource for setting this up. I looked and interceptor is an accepted property of a resource.

Comment: instead of interceptor in every call you should use global interceptor like above sample code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I just needed to do the following:

```
service('PortfolioService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/', {}, {
        stock_positions: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/stock_positions',
            isArray: false,
            interceptor:{
                response:function(response){
                    //do stuff here to catch the response before passing it on.
                    return response;
                },
                responseError: function(rejection){
                    console.log(rejection);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}]).
```

Comment: Hi what about catching the request in interceptor?

Comment: nvm found it from angularjs docs, request can be pushed as well in interceptors.